# how to download instagram reels in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, instagram-api, instagram-reels

is there any way to download instagram reels in flutter without using the official api? I've tried various api's and packages from pub but none of them works , let me know if there is any unofficial api

Answer (score 1):

Here you can examine a project similar to the subject you want.
https://github.com/ravindravala/Flutter-Reels-downloader-for-instagram

You can install the flutter_reels_downloader package in a .yaml file and examine it as in the example.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reels_downloader/example

[image]

I hope I could help. Enjoy your work.

Comment: ive already checked this, its not working